# How to prevent inoremap mapping from being "run" inside iabbrev?

Tags: key-bindings, abbreviations

I have the following abbreviation:

```
iabbrev .d. [[2021-12-02]]
```

I also have the following remap:

```
inoremap [[ [[]]<Left><Left>
```

The problem is, whenever I type `.d.` to get the date string, I get the following output:

```
[[2021-12-02]] ]]
```

It looks like the additional (unwanted) `]]` are a result of the `inoremap` being executed while the abbreviation is resolved.

How can I prevent the `inoremap` from being "run" inside the `iabbrev`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `inoreabbrev` instead. This will prevent the recursive `inoremap`.